# C#: Converting List of Chars to String

Tags: c#, string

I'm solving a coding challenge on Coderbyte with C# using lists. I have the desired outcome but need to return it as a string.

I would like to know how to convert my list of chars into a string.
Thank you in advance.

Here's my code:

```
string s = "I love dogs";
int i, j = 0;
List<char> array1 = new List<char>();
List<char> array2 = new List<char>();

for (i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    if (s.Length == j)
        break;

    if (Char.IsLetter(s[i]))
    {
        array1.Add(s[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        for (j = i; j < s.Length; j++)
        {
            if (Char.IsLetter(s[j]))
            {
                array2.Add(s[i]);
            }
            if (!Char.IsLetter(s[j]) || j == s.Length - 1)
            {
                if (array1.Count >= array2.Count)
                {
                    array2.Clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    array1.Clear();
                    array1.AddRange(array2);
                    array2.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
} // How to convert array1 into String ?
```

Comment: `string result = new string(array1.ToArray());`

Comment: While you *could* keep them as lists, I'd suggest using `StringBuilder` instead of `List<char>`. As far as I can see, everything you're doing with the lists, you could do with `StringBuilder` instead. Then just call `ToString` at the end.

Comment: @René Vogt this has worked thank you very much!

Comment: @Jon Skeet will consider StringBuilder next time :)!

Comment: Any reason for not changing to use it right now? It's designed for precisely this sort of task. Unless this is really throw-away code, I'd say that using StringBuilder is significantly more idiomatic.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

One option for this is to use the [string constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8):

```
var myString = new string(array1.ToArray());
```

Comment: var myString = string.Join("", array)

Comment: `var myString = String.Concat(array1); ` is a better answer here. It is faster and allocates less memory.